# Can't read attribute '2' from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an error because I want to search in the second column of my Google Spreadsheet the match for a string `'o'` and at the line `if (data[n][2] == 'o')` I get an error If you have an idea  because I'm blocked for a long time with this:)

I've put the constants as global variables :

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = "...."; // = assign your spreadsheet id to this variable
var SHEET_NAME = "main"; // = assign your sheet name to this variable
var FOLDER_ID = "....."

function create_Google_Docs_2019() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // à partir de 2 car la première ligne ne nous interesse pas
  for(n=2;n<=data.length;++n) {

  //verifier si c'est une projet 2019
    if (data[n][2] == 'o')
      nombre_projets_2019 = nombre_projets_2019  + 1;
  }
  Logger.log('Nombre de projets 2019 ' +  nombre_projets_2019 );

}
```

Edit: Sorry for the mistakes and thank you I don't know if it's important this is a standard alone script in the same folder as my Spreadsheet document.

Edit edit : I tried like in the comment below thanks very much and this is my final code

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues()
    
      
      var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
      Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());
      
 
      var nombre_projets_2019 = 0 ;
      
      
      // the second row because the first is not important
       for(n=1;n < data.length;n++) {
        
        //verify if we have 'o' so we will create the corresponded document
         if ( data[n][1] == 'o'){
          nombre_projets_2019 = nombre_projets_2019  + 1;
  }
  Logger.log('Nombre de projets 2019 ' +  nombre_projets_2019 );

}
```

Comment: You get that error on the final loop, when your value of `n` is the same as the length of `data`. Because arrays are 0-base indexed, the last index that is defined is index `data[data.length-1]`. Change the conditional expression of your `for` loop from `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inspect the 2nd column, you'll want to use `data[n][1]`. Arrays are 0-indexed, so the first column is `0`, the second column is `1`, etc.

More importantly, your foot loop is incorrectly specified.

Using `<=` is causing the  loop to extend 1 beyond the length of the loop. You want to use `<` instead.

Also, taking into account 0-indexing, your loop is starting on the third row.

So, if you want to avoid going out of bounds and analyze starting with the second row, initialize your for loop like this:

```
for (n = 1; n < data.length; n++) {
```

Comment: I did as you said but I got the same error but this time it is the 1 from undefined as I edited the post

Comment: Why do you think that the prefix and postfix operators in the final expression are different when they are both executed at the end of the loop (hence why the third expression is the "final expression")? If you are using a JavaScript engine that doesn't optimize tiny things, then writing prefix is arguably faster. Please review how `for` loops work. Note that you make the same mistake as OP, and your second expression in the for loop will result in an access of undefined index on the final iteration. The correct second expression is `n < data.length`

Comment: Thanks. Removed the increment operator observation since it was totally off base.

Comment: @anamaria Can you update your for loop to match my recent edit? (i.e. `<` instead of `<=`.